# Notice: Undefined index: mtral_field_subscriber

Tags: plugins, wp-redirect

> Notice: Undefined index: mtral_field_subscriber in
>   /wp-content/plugins/redirect-after-login/redirect-after-login.php
>   on line 54
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /wp-content/plugins/redirect-after-login/redirect-after-login.php:54)
>   in wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
>   1219

I get the above error and the error occurs specifically after I login since I am using Redirect After Login plugin in wordpress

How can I debug and fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove that plugin, and create that redirection youself.

You can use the `login_redirect` hook, add this into your theme's `functions.php`

```
function redirect_admin( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){

    //is there a user to check?

    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {

            $redirect_to = get_site_url().'/a-page/'; // Your redirect URL
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_admin', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score -1):

> How can I debug and fix it ?

The issue is straightforward and the error identifies the specific file and line number that it's occurring on, but since this is a plugin it's something that the plugin author has to fix. You need to contact them and tell them to fix it or find another plugin.

That being said, a PHP notice like this is a minor issue, not something that should appear in production in front of the public. To prevent errors appearing to the public, in your wp-config.php file set `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `false`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

But to keep a log of any errors, set `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to `true`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

Comment: :( hiding errors do not fix them. All security bugs start with unintended execution flow that this kind of errors provide

Comment: They're not being hidden, they're being logged and should be actioned, but in production errors shouldn't be shown to end users.

Comment: yes, but that is in no way an answer to the question of debugging and fixing it, it is an answer to "how do I avoid the error being displayed"

Comment: and all errors are not "minor". The severity is just something to indicate that the code will continue to execute, it is not indicates that the cause or other possible impacts are minor

Comment: My first paragraph is the answer: No debugging needs to be done because the issue is obvious from the error message, and the fix needs to be done by the plugin's developer. The only 'fix' they can implement without them is to deactivate the plugin, which was suggested. And no, not all errors a minor, but they still shouldn't be public in production.

Comment: debugging should be done to find why it happens. all you know is that there is a corrupted DB at that point in the code, but the reason why are unknown and you need to find them out before you can attempt a fix. But I know that you know that.... The answer as is just emphasizes the wrong things

Comment: probably would not have had much beef with it if it was also stated in the answer. Maybe something like "you should report the issue to the plugin author as in any case you should not change plugins you did not write", and that would probably been the almost best answer. Actually I planned to only leave a comment but then I saw I wasn't the only only one thinking it is an iffy answer.